# How can I set up a byte stream out of a mix of strings and numbers?

Tags: python, arrays

My goal is to set up a byte array which I can fill up with string elements, ints, other byte arrays and so on. Eventually I want to send this byte array to the serial interface.

For exmple:

```
preamble = "ABC"
payloadSize = 10 #supposed to represent a uint32_t value
payload = bytearray(payloadSize)
crc = bytearray(4);
postamble = "CBA"
```

this should now be concatenated to a single bytearray that then can be fed into

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(...)

txBuffer= bytearray(...)

#... adding here "somehow" the preamble, payloadsize, payload, crc and postamble to the txBuffer.

ser.write(txBuffer)
```

where the packet should look like

```
b'A B C 0 0 0 10 pp pp pp pp pp pp pp pp pp pp  cc cc cc cc C B A'
```

pp stays for payload byte, cc for crc byte

Found "a" solution after processing comments and try and error ...(thx for comments):

```
index = 3
txBuffer[:index] = bytes(preamble, 'ascii')
txBuffer[index] = payloadSize >> 24 & 0xFF
index += 1
txBuffer[index] = payloadSize >> 16 & 0xFF
index += 1
txBuffer[index] = payloadSize >> 8  & 0xFF
index += 1
txBuffer[index] = payloadSize       & 0xFF

for i in range(index, payloadSize):
    txBuffer[i] = payload[i]

index += payloadSize

txBuffer[index] = crc[0]
index += 1
txBuffer[index] = crc[1]
index += 1
txBuffer[index] = crc[2]
index += 1
txBuffer[index] = crc[3]

txBuffer[index:] = postamble
```

Hmm, this would work. Any recommendation for doing it better?

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray? If you want to put things that aren't bytes in it, maybe you don't want a byte array?

Comment: Ha that's exactelly what I try. I want to
a = bytearray(10)
b = "abc"
a[0] = bytes(b[0], 'ascii')

But still fails for reasons. Both seams to be of type "byte" but checking it out the hard way one has to find out that bytearray then makes an int array instead of a "BYTE ARRAY"

Comment: `bytearray`s aren't arrays of `bytes` objects (which are *also* sequences of integers, an *"immutable version of `bytearray`"* per the docs I already linked), they're arrays *of bytes*, of integers. `a[0] = bytes("a", "ascii")[0]` would work just fine, for example.

Comment: Why don't you write this into an "Answer"?

Comment: Because this is already explained in the docs, and it's unclear what you're really trying to achieve. You're asking how to get a "real byte array" when that's what you *already have*.

Comment: What is unclear with: "My goal is to set up a byte array which I can fill up with string elements, ints, other byte arrays and so on. Eventually I want to send this byte array to the serial interface."

Comment: What's unclear is that that's a description of an array of bytes you want to put *things that aren't bytes* into, which doesn't make any sense. Maybe you just want a regular list? Please [edit] to give some more useful context rather than repeating the same things that are already unclear.

Comment: Hmm, is it better now?

Comment: You can do what you're now describing *with a `bytearray`*. Try `txBuffer[:3] = b"abc"`, for example. You just can't assign multiple bytes (e.g. the content of a whole `bytes` object) to a single byte (one index of a `bytearray` object), you have to take into account how many bytes you're dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this should now be concatenated to a single bytearray

Well, you can concatenate bytearrays, or bytearrays with `b'...'` strings.

```
>>> bytearray(b'abc') + b'def'
bytearray(b'abcdef')
```

As for encoding ints, the [`struct` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) might be what you want. E.g. packing a little-endian unsigned long (see the part on [Format Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings) on that page):

```
>>> struct.pack("<L", 0x11121314);
b'\x14\x13\x12\x11'
```

So, all in all, would something like this work?

```
preamble = b'ABCD'
payload = b'hello!\0'
payloadsize = len(payload)
txbuf = bytearray(preamble + struct.pack("!L", payloadsize) + payload)
```

Now `txbuf` should be `bytearray(b'ABCD\x00\x00\x00\x07hello!\x00')`.

Or if you want to preallocate it and fill in-place, not that I have any idea if that matters:

```
txbuf = bytearray(20)
txbuf[0:4] = preamble
txbuf[4:8] = struct.pack("!L", payloadsize)
txbuf[8: 8 + payloadsize] = payload
```

That should leave it as `bytearray(b'ABCD\x00\x00\x00\x07hello!\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')`.

Comment: Badamm... thats an answer. Would have liked to give at least 10 points for it. Very helpful it is! Thank you very much!